# Download Original XAP from Dev Center

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store, windows-store

I have a Windows Phone 8/8.1 App in the Windows Phone App Store. Unfortunately, I have lost the source due to system crash. Now, I want to decompile the XAP file. For decompilation I have downloaded JustDecompile from Telerik. But it fails to decompile the XAP file that I get from the store. I have an idea that the file is encrypted.

Is there a way to get the original file that I created using Visual Studio, as it is still available somewhere on the dev center (It shows the file name as published app)?

[image: Filename shown]

Is there any other workaround to get the source back from XAP?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. I really need my app project back.

Comment: It's not possible via publically available tools. XAP from the Windows Store is encrypted and can't be disassembled (with publically available tools). Try to search at xda-developers.com

Comment: Is there a way get the unencrypted XAP back? The original one that I uploaded?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal Source control is your friend, better if it's offsite.  A long shot, but do you still have the `bin/debug` folder?

Comment: I even don't have the original XAP (which is there in `bin/debug` folder by default). I will decompile/regenerate if I can get my original XAP back.

Answer (score 0):

Install the app on your SD card. Then plug in the SD card into PC, change `view` property to show system files. Now, you can get into apps installation folder and get your dll's now.

Comment: I will give this a try and post back.

Comment: Sure. I am not completely sure about the name of the folder which has the installation files, but the folder exists

Comment: Still arranging for a phone that supports sd cards.

Comment: Whats your app called on store? Can you give the link?

Comment: Its called Dimernsions Weather and News.
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-au/store/app/dimensions-weather-and-news/9b98f81f-0b33-4075-bae0-9030177fc20f

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66090/discussion-between-karthik-nishanth-and-samarth-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone store xap files are encrypted. So you will not be able retrieve the files using store installed xap file. You might be able to contact the Dev center support team to see if they can provide the original xap file. I'm not sure if it is possible but you can give a try.

http://dev.windows.com/en-us/community/support ==> Publishing apps as support option.

Comment: Did that. No luck. They say that they don't keep the original XAP files.